# windows page file policy

Tags: windows, paging

Generally my question is why Windows is constantly thrashing my HDD. I'm talking about Windows 7 to be exact (and of course indexing is turned off).
I have a feeling that this is related to the page file, because this phenomenon disappears when the page file is turned off.
More specifically, my question is why Windows ever makes a use of the page file, whereas the amount of RAM is not exhausted yet.

I have two possible explanations:

1. perhaps Windows tends to save memory pages of every running process to the page file "in background" even before this is really needed. Then when free RAM is eventually needed - it can be acquired more quickly.
2. In kernel mode paging is not always possible. Drivers that run at high IRQL can use only physical RAM. Hence the OS should have some reserve of RAM that drivers may wish to allocate dynamically.

Anyway I'm talking about reserve of GBs free RAM, yet Windows is thrashing HDD.

Does anybody knows what's the exact Windows policy regarding the page file, and if it can be adjusted?

Of course I can turn the page file off, but I **do** want to use it, but **only** when RAM is adequately exhausted.

BTW I thought about buying in SSD as a system driver, but I'm afraid it'll be dead in a year with this kind of an abuse.

Comment: please don't use that word it is deeply offensive

Comment: That would be atypical behavior, perfmon -> memory & look at the pages IO counters to confirm its paging that's causing the thrashing, if not filemon to see what is. Look @ the answers given to http://serverfault.com/questions/23621/any-benefit-or-detriment-from-removing-a-pagefile-on-an-8gb-ram-machine

Comment: @David Heffernan: sorry, I won't

Comment: @Alex K.: Thanks for the link. This makes sense (though written in a bit populistic manner). This is what I thought more-or-less. But what if I **don't want** to preliminary store everything on HDD? I'd like to define a memory watermark, beyond which Windows should start "saving" things to the page file.

Comment: @Alex K.: In other words: it's stated that Windows tries to optimize its performance under the peak load, at expense of the performance in the normal conditions. Disabling the page file does the opposite: best performance in normal conditions, at expense of exhaust at peak load.  And I want a ballance: uncompromised performance in normal conditions, and reasonable (though suboptimal) performance at high load.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons for disk activity in Windows 7: indexing (turned off here), scheduled tasks (collection of usage information, check disk etc.), disk defrag, antivirus, SuperFetch, paging and many more. You are correct to suspect that paging can happen even when there is sufficient RAM and the reason you have is correct. They call is pre-emptive paging to prepare system for spikes of memory demand. Once you have large amounts of RAM this seems unnecessary and it is in 99% of time. 1% are all those situations when you actually run out of memory and paging is the only option. There is a solution to get best of both worlds. You can practically eliminate paging and still have page file by setting its minimum size to something very small. If you are fine with mini kernel dumps to be done when system crashes you can set page file minimum size to be just 16 MB. If you want full kernel dumps, minimum is 1 GB but that would limit paging to a lesser degree. Set maximum page file size to 4 GB or whatever you want.

This way Windows can always expand and use bigger page if it REALLY needs to (out of virtual memory) but should not use it under normal condition. Probably never. You still keep the safety net of page file though.